# AppleScript: complex script for WIFI login, getting time and launch screensaver

Tags: wifi, applescript, script, screensaver

Experts!

I'm new to apple script and struggling with its complexity...But maybe someone can help.
The thing I want to do my iMac:

The iMac is used to work as a HighEnd slideshow for an artist work. Its extremely important that the iMac gets the correct time for displaying the slideshow.

So what the iMac needs to do:

- iMac wakes up every morning at 8 AM and gets to sleep at 11 PM (done by Energysaver)
- iMac toggles Wifi on and off (see script1 below)
- Starting Safari (script 2)
- iMac finds the correct Wifi and logs in (missing)
- Login Page of Wifi needs a "click in checkbox" to accept terms of use (SCRIPT 3 I tried to adapt a script found on the net, but doesn't really work)
- iMac waits until a dedicated time (9 AM) and launches screensaver. (SCRIPT 4 is launching, but waiting until specific time is missing)

Any helps & suggestions would be very much appreciated!!
Andreas

What I have:

--SCRIPT 1

```
set status to do shell script "networksetup -getairportpower en1"

if status ends with "On" then

    do shell script "networksetup -setairportpower en1 off; sleep 2"

end if


set status to do shell script "networksetup -getairportpower en1"

if status ends with "Off" then

    do shell script "networksetup -setairportpower en1 on"

end if
```

--SCRIPT 2

```
tell application "Safari" activate

end tell
```

--SCRIPT 3 clicking the box to accept terms of use

```
to clickID(theId) 

    tell application "Safari"

        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('" & theId & "').click();" in document 1 

    end tell 

end clickID
```

--SCRIPT 4 is needed to get the time, wait and launch screensaver

```
set ntpdPID to do shell script "pgrep ntpd; exit 0"

if ntpdPID is not "" then

    do shell script "systemsetup -setusingnetworktime On" with administrator privileges

end if

try

    tell application id "com.apple.Screensaver.engine" to launch

end try
```

Comment: We can not help with script 3 unless we have the source code of the page. Please edit your question to include relevant sections of the html.

Comment: From a personal perspective, any *digital signage* project I did, thing I found most useful was *not* connecting the machine to the same network that everyone else was using - especially not a (free) public network.  This did two things:  1) ensured that the machine had connectivity and 2) prevented unauthorized access.  This is something you should investigate further; specifically, look at using VLANs and (where applicable) different SSIDs

Comment: THANKS TO ALL FOR YOUR VALUABLE HELP!!! I am really impressed for getting so much help from you guys! I will now check and post the code of the website - will take a few days because I will be on a business trip....

Comment: @Allan +1 Very good point. I would probably suggest using a WPA2 secured network for the machine. It would be easier to script. While allowing the captive portal one for guests.

Comment: @Allen & JBis Thanks for this hint! I will check if I can install a secured network for the machine. Additionally it seems that the public network I wanted to use is not reliable enough to ensure proper connection...

Answer (score 1):

### WIP

---

### Script 1

```
repeat 2 times
    set status to do shell script "networksetup -getairportpower en0"
    if status ends with "On" then
        do shell script "networksetup -setairportpower en1 off"
        delay 2
    else
        do shell script "networksetup -setairportpower en1 on"
    end if
end repeat
```

---

### Script 2

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
```

---

### Script 2.5

Use @CJK code to connect. Then use Script 3 to accept terms and conditions.

---

### Script 3

1. Safari > Preferences > Advanced > Show Develop menu in menu bar
2. Develop > Allow JavaScript from Apple Events

3.

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    make new document with properties {URL: "http://captive.apple.com"}
    if not (exists document 1) then reopen
    tell current tab of window 1 to set URL to "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500011/how-to-wait-for-webpage-to-fully-load-before-proceeding-script"
    set the_state to missing value
    repeat until the_state is "complete"
        set the_state to (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1)
        delay 0.2
    end repeat
    set theId to "WillBeAddedOnceCodeIsAddedInQuestion"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('" & theId & "').click();" in document 1
end tell
```

---

### Script 4

If the script is working then do the following:

**Cron Method (Depreciated)**

1.

```
export VISUAL=nano; crontab -e
```

2. Copy and paste the following

```
0 9 * * * osascript /path/to/YourAppleScript.scpt
```

3. Press ^O (Control + O)

4. Press Enter

**Note:** [Cron will not execute if the computer is asleep](https://superuser.com/questions/14836/crontab-to-wake-osx-from-sleep#14846)

**launchd**

1. sudo nano /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mycompany.plist
2. Copy and paste the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.mycompany.daemon</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
        <string>/path/to/YourAppleScript.scpt</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>9</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

3. Press ^O (Control + O)
4. Press Enter

5.

```
 sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mycompany.plist
```

---

Comment: As CJK points out, `launchd` is probably preferable over `cron`, the latter of which is considered deprecated on macOS. `StartCalendarInterval` would probably be the key to use here.

Comment: Although deprecated, it does work and is a bit more simple especially for simple things like this. If it was anything more complicated I would use launchd. Anyway I will edit question to include that option.

Comment: Lots of Users have reported issues with getting **Allow JavaScript from Apple Events** on the **Develop** menu of **Safari** to work. For me at first in macOS High Sierra, it just wouldn't toggle no matter what I tried as suggested in countless posts. Then it toggled on, and a bit later I toggled it off and it would not work further. Weeks later I was able to get the check mark to show, but not going to turn it off for now, as I need it. BTW It will read much better if you put some `space` around `>` when you use them, e.g. Safari > Preferences > Advanced> Show Develop menu in menu bar, etc.

Comment: `open location` is not a _Safari_ command and shouldn't be used inside a _Safari_ `tell` block (or, rather, it's superfluous doing so).  `open location` opens a URL in the system's **default** browser, which may be _Chrome_.  To open a URL in _Safari_, do `tell app "Safari" to make new document with properties {URL: "http://example.com"}`.